# CouchDB multikey view with an array

Tags: javascript, couchdb, pouchdb, couchdb-2.0

Okay, so my problem is that I have a multikey view, that works.

```
function (docu) {
  if(!docu.deleted){
    emit([docu.key1, docu.key2, docu.key3], docu);
  }
}
```

I am attempting to add another key to this already multi-key array. The key I am attempting to add is an array of string values,

```
[
"test",
"test2"
]
```

I am querying my view using `PouchDB` and its built in query method, code is below.

```
database.query("views/viewTest", {
    startkey: [key1, key2, key3, key4],
    endkey: [key1, key2, key3, key4],
    reduce: false
}, function (err, res) {
    if (err) {
        console.log(err);
        alert(err);
    } else {
        console.log(res);
    }
});
```

Where `key4` is my new array. I have a little luck with my map function by changing it to `emit([docu.key1, docu.key2, docu.key3, [docu.key4]], docu);` but this only works if there is only one item in the array, and I need it to work for multiple items in the array.

I can't figure out how to set up my view or query to utilize multiple items in my `key4` array.

I have tried querying with `startkey` and `endkey`, where `key4` had an `{}` pushed into it for the `endkey`, but this returned everything. I only want the values returned within the `key4` array, as long as they match the other keys as well.

So to sum:

- My view/query works before I add in the new key4 array.
- The view/query works if the key4 array has ONE item in it.
- I need it to work for ALL items in the key4 array.
- I have tried multiple things and can/could not get this to work.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use a unique array that concats key4 to [key1, key2, key3]?

```
function (docu) {
  if(!docu.deleted){
    var key = [docu.key1, docu.key2, docu.key3].concat(doc.key4);
    emit(key, docu);
  }
}
```

Comment: They problem is that `key4` from the Document will always be one item, a `String`, whereas when I search in the `start/endkey` it will be an `Array` of `String`s. So I need a way for the `map` to be able to grab the input and test if `key4` from the document is inside the `start/endkey` key4, and emit those.